# onbeforeunload canceling dialog deactivates all buttons/links/

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I have to add an onbeforeunload event with "data loss" warning dialog in a JSF 1.2 IceFaces context.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
        if (dirty) {
            event.returnValue = "qwe";
            return "wer";
        } else {
            event.stopPropagation();
            return;
        }
        console.log("TEST", dirty);
    });
});
```

If I cancel the dialog all my links and buttons (inclusive main menu) have no reaction on mouse clicks ... custom JS events still work but if the link points to a method in managed bean or something else there is no reaction until I reload the page.

Have anyone an idea how to fix or debug it?

Greetz
Dennis

Comment: I can't imagine why that would be, but two issues with the code you've shown: 1. You haven't declared the `event` parameter, so you're relying on the global `event`, which will bite you on Firefox where it doesn't exist. 2. There's no need for your `else` branch at all. If you don't want the dialog, just don't return anything from the handler. So perhaps update those and see if the problem goes away...

Comment: This question has nothing whatsoever to do with [tag:java] or [tag:jsf-1.2]. Please don't tag-spam. I've added the [tag:javascript] since it *does* relate to JavaScript.

Comment: Thx for info, @T.J.Crowder, I really think its a JSF problem. Because all common JS events still work after canceling the dialog. My first assumption is, that java already handled the unload. JSF 1.2 is very old and maybe it cannot handle an abort of page reload. Thats the reason why I added the tags to my topic. :)

Comment: i fixed the JS code (removed else branch) and the problem still exists.